# Editing an array inside an object inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a challenge for a coding class, and for some reason my code won't work. I was given the following:

```
// Setup
var collection = {
    2548: {
      album: "Slippery When Wet",
      artist: "Bon Jovi",
      tracks: [ 
        "Let It Rock", 
        "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
      ]
    },
    2468: {
      album: "1999",
      artist: "Prince",
      tracks: [ 
        "1999", 
        "Little Red Corvette" 
      ]
    },
    1245: {
      artist: "Robert Palmer",
      tracks: [ ]
    },
    5439: {
      album: "ABBA Gold"
    }
};
// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

// Only change code below this line
```

I was supposed to fulfill the following:

- After updateRecords(5439, "artist", "ABBA"), artist should be "ABBA"
- After updateRecords(5439, "tracks", "Take a Chance on Me"), tracks should have "Take a Chance on Me" as the last element.
- After updateRecords(2548, "artist", ""), artist should not be set
- After updateRecords(1245, "tracks", "Addicted to Love"), tracks should have "Addicted to Love" as the last element.
- After updateRecords(2548, "tracks", ""), tracks should not be set

My code is only fulfilling the first and 4th requirements. When running `updateRecords(5439, "tracks", "Take a Chance on Me");` or `updateRecords(2548, "tracks", "");`, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. When I run `updateRecords(2548, "artist", "");`, I get `TypeError: Cannor convert undefined or null to object`.

My code looks like this:

```
// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if (value !== "" && prop !== "tracks"){
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }
  else if (value !== "" && prop == "tracks"){
    var currentAlbumTracks = collection[id].tracks;
    currentAlbumTracks.push(value);
  }
  else if (value === ""){
    delete collection.id.prop;
  }
  return collection;
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

***EDIT:*** I've changed my code a bit. Now I have:

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  var currentAlbumTracks = collection[id].tracks;
  if (value !== "") {
    if (prop !== "tracks"){
      collection[id][prop] = value;
    }
    else if (prop == "tracks"){
      if (currentAlbumTracks) {
       currentAlbumTracks.push(value);
      }
      else if (currentAlbumTracks === ""){
        collection[id].tracks = [value];
      }
    }
  }

  return collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have two mistakes here.

1. `collection[id].tracks` is `undefined` in some cases, so before pushing values you need to define it, So

   ```
   var currentAlbumTracks = collection[id].tracks;
   currentAlbumTracks.push(value);
   ```

   became

   ```
   collection[id].tracks = collection[id].tracks || []; //Take existing or create new
   collection[id].tracks.push(value);
   ```
2. Your dot notation is incorrect, more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

   So

   ```
   delete collection.id.prop;
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   delete collection[id][prop];
   ```

Overall including all rectification, We can make following function

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if (value !== "" && prop !== "tracks"){
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }
  else if (value !== "" && prop == "tracks"){
    collection[id].tracks = collection[id].tracks || [];
    collection[id].tracks.push(value);
  }
  else if (value === ""){
    delete collection[id][prop];
  }
  return collection;
}
```

Comment: I had no idea you could use the logical OR with declarations. That makes it so much easier. Thanks so much, your code worked!

Answer (score 0):

You posted two errors.

1. This error comes from your attempt to call `push` on `collection[id].tracks`. If the `tracks` property has not been set yet on the `collection[id]` record, it is not yet an `Array`, and therefore does not have a `push` method. You will have to check whether the `Array` exists before attempting to `push` to it, or you can pre-assign an empty `Array` to the `tracks` property for each record.
2. The second error may be the result of your switch from bracket-notation to dot-notation when referencing properties; you refer to `collection.id.prop`, whereas in all previous cases you refer to `collection[id][prop]`.

Answer (score 0):

The error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` in the line `currentAlbumTracks.push(value);` means that `currentAlbumTracks` is undefined. You need to guard against this possibility:

```
var currentAlbumTracks = collection[id].tracks;
if (currentAlbumTracks) {
   currentAlbumTracks.push(value);
}
```

The error `TypeError: Cannor convert undefined or null to object` in the line `delete collection.id.prop;` shows a similar problem. You're  trying to access the property named 'prop' which doesn't exist in any of the elements. So you want bracket notation here.

```
if (collection.id[prop]) {
   delete collection.id[prop];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured the first part out shortly after posting. Now my only question is how do I create the array with the value of [value]?

Comment: I don't understand your question :(

Comment: I want to make the array and give it a value of whatever the user says. I'm trying to do `collection[id].tracks = [value];`, and it no longer gives an error, but it doesn't add anything to the JSON tree.

Comment: If the object with that id already has a `tracks` array, it won't add anything, it will replace it with whatever you say. But if it doesn't, then I don't see why it shouldn't modify the tree..

Comment: I tried to simplify the code. Now I have the code in the edit of the OP